# Create a new bundle symfony 3 error

Tags: symfony

I have a problem with my creation of new bundle :
My `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
app_desktop:
resource: "@AppDesktopBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /
```

My `src/App/DesktopBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`

```
app_desktop_homepage:
path:     /
defaults: { _controller: AppDesktopBundle:Default:index }
```

In `/src/App/DekstopBundle/Controller/DefaultController` I have a method :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('AppDesktopBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

And also I have an template asociated. I make an cache:clear from console but I have this error :

```
Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
```

Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Can you post the exactly error message? You have check to have `index.html.twig` file in `Resources/views folder`?

Comment: It seems like you're using the prod environment. Can you use the dev environment to have a more specific error message and post it here please?